# jQuery smoth scrolling não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet, rolamento

Quando clico uma vez em uma das opções da `nav`, ele funciona, mas se dou um duplo clique ou se eu estiver numa área e clicar para ir em outra, ele se perde e *buga* total, não sei o que fazer e já tentei usar todas as JS possíveis.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-transparente ">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <!-- botao toggle -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao">
            <span class="sr-only">alternar navegação</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a href="#conteudo-sobre" class="js-scroll-trigger">
            <img src="logopng.png" width="100" height="30" style="margin-top: 10px">
          </a>

        </div>

        <!-- navbar -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra-navegacao">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a id="home" href="#conteudo-home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="sobre" href="#conteudo-sobre">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a id="servicos" href="#conteudo-servicos">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a id="contato" href="#conteudo-contato">Contato</a></li>
            <li class="divisor" role="separator"></li>
            <li><a id="msc" href="#conteudo-contato">Mande seu currículo</a></li>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /container -->
    </nav><!-- /nav -->

    <div class="capa " id="conteudo-home">

        <div class="texto-capa layer">
        <img src="logopng.png" width="450" height="150" >
        <h4><hr align="center" width="100" size="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae pha</h4>
        <a href="#conteudo-sobre" class="btn btn-custom btn-branco btn-lg">Saiba mais</a>

      </div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setBindings();
});

function setBindings() {
    $("nav a").click(function(e){
       //e.preventDefault();

        e.preventDefault();

        var sectionID = "conteudo-" + e.currentTarget.id;


        $("html body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000)

        //alert("-" + e.currentTarget.id);



   //    var sectionID = "conteudo-" e.currentTarget.id;

    //   alert(sectionID + "id");



/*
    $("html body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top

    },1000)

*/
    })

}
```

Comment: digamos que possui um botao Home, sobre e contato, se eu estou no home e clico em sobre ele desce tranquilo, mas se clico no sobre de novo ele volta pro home, isso nao deveria acontecer ,

Comment: e quando estou no sobre e clico para contato, ele simplesmete rola pra cima do nada,

Comment: exatamente!!, mas infelizmente nao estou conseguindo de maneira nenhuma

Comment: claro, isso ja me ajudaria bastante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É preciso fazer algumas modificações no seu código pra isso funcionar. Siga os passos abaixo:

**a) Retire os nomes do `href`, deixe apenas o `#`:**

```
<li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="sobre" href="#">Sobre</a></li>
<li><a id="servicos" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
<li><a id="contato" href="#">Contato</a></li>
<li class="divisor" role="separator"></li>
<li><a id="contato" href="#">Mande seu currículo</a></li>
```

**b) Retire esta função desnecessária (não apague o que tem dentro dela):**

```
function setBindings() {...
```

Não esqueça de apagar a chave `}` que fecha ela.

**c) Apague isso também que chama a função acima:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setBindings();
});
```

**d) Altere esta linha:**

```
var sectionID = "conteudo-" + e.currentTarget.id;
```

para

```
var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");
```

**e) Troque isto:**

```
$("html body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
}, 1000)
```

por isto:

```
$("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: $("#conteudo-" + sectionID).offset().top
}, "slow");
```

Com essas alterações seu código deve funcionar.

```js
$("nav a").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");
   $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#conteudo-" + sectionID).offset().top
   }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-transparente ">
   <div class="container">
      <!-- header -->
      <div class="navbar-header">

         <!-- botao toggle -->
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao">
            <span class="sr-only">alternar navegação</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>

         <a href="#conteudo-sobre" class="js-scroll-trigger">
            <img src="logopng.png" width="100" height="30" style="margin-top: 10px">
         </a>

      </div>

      <!-- navbar -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra-navegacao">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="sobre" href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a id="servicos" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a id="contato" href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <li class="divisor" role="separator"></li>
            <li><a id="contato" href="#">Mande seu currículo</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div><!-- /container -->
</nav><!-- /nav -->
<div class="capa " id="conteudo-home">
   <div class="texto-capa layer">
      <img src="logopng.png" width="450" height="150" >
      <h4><hr align="center" width="100" size="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae pha</h4>
      <a href="#conteudo-sobre" class="btn btn-custom btn-branco btn-lg">Saiba mais</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="capa " id="conteudo-sobre">
   sobre
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="capa " id="conteudo-servicos">
   servicos
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="capa " id="conteudo-contato">
   contato
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```